# Java: Dividing integers to double doesn't work

Tags: java

```
public class SumAndAverage {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int sum = 0;
        int num;
        for(num = 0; num <= 100; num++){ 
            sum += num; 
        }

        double average = ((double)sum) / num;
        System.out.println("The sum is " + sum);
        System.out.println("The average is " + average);

    }
}
```

RESULT:

The sum is 5050
The average is 50.0

What's wrong:

5050 / 100 = 50.5 
NOT 
50.0

Comment: I do not see where you divide integers "to double". To double means to multiply with 2. You divide doubles by integers.

Answer (score 6):

When this loop finishes

```
for(num = 0; num <= 100; num++){
```

`num` is `101`, not `100`. Because what happens is that the condition is tested until it's false, and this happens when `num>100`.

Answer (score 0):

You got it wrong. That's what happens when you don't use variables as loop checks (and when you use magic numbers anti-pattern in general)- and reuse those later. That way you are certain what value you will actually use.

```
public class SumAndAverage {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int sum = 0;
        int num;
        int max = 100;
        for(num = 0; num <= max; num++){ 
            sum += num; 
        }

        double average = ((double)sum) / max;
        System.out.println("The sum is " + sum);
        System.out.println("The average is " + average);

    }
}
```

Your num was equal to 101, not 100...

Comment: @user2864740 - What do you mean it doesn't fix it?  This code gives the correct result.  The bug is gone.

Answer (score 0):

Variable num will be 101 when it comes out of loop. So you need to manually subtract one or below can do the same job better with one iteration less

```
for(num = 0; num < 100; ){ 
    sum += ++num; 
}
```

**Full Program**

```
public class SumAndAverage {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int sum = 0;
    int num;
    for(num = 0; num < 100; ){ 
        sum += ++num; 
    }

    double average = ((double)sum) / num;
    System.out.println("The sum is " + sum);
    System.out.println("The average is " + average);
}
}
```

Check it.